# BootStrap select has wrong width when adding prepend

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm making login page and wanted to put icon before select with prepend so it would indicate that you can change language here, when I added it, select width become wrong, it's a little too big on right side (like on screenshot below)

[image: screenshot]

```
<div class="input-group">

                <div class="input-group-prepend offset-2 offset-md-3">
                    <div class="input-group-text">
                        <i class="fas fa-globe-europe"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <select class="form-control col-8 col-md-6" name="lang" onchange="this.form.submit();">

                        <optgroup label="Official Languages">
                            <option value="en" selected="">English (United States)</option>
                            <option value="pl">Polski (Polska)</option>
                        </optgroup>
                        <optgroup label="Community Translations (not checked by us)">
                            <option value="es">Español (España)</option>
                        </optgroup>

                        </select>                           

                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12 text-center">
                                <span onclick="window.open(dir+'popup/unofficial-translations','popupUNOFFTRANSL','height=500,width=1000,left=100,top=100,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=no');" style="font-size: 1.8vh" class="text-muted"><abbr>Click here to learn more about unofficial translations</abbr></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12 text-center">
                                <span style="font-size: 1.8vh" class="text-muted">Change of language will remove written login and password.</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: please add your html

Comment: @NicolásAlarcónRapela Please don't [introduce thanks into any posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288160/6296561). I'm aware you're required to have 6 chars to submit the edit, but adding "thanks" and similar is more likely to get your edits rejected rather than approved, if it otherwise is unsubstantial

Comment: forgot, added code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't show your code beside your rendered dropdown, I am going to guess your rest HTML structure.

The one problem I see from your code is you don't have `.row` when using `.col-*`. You need to wrap your columns with at least a row. Of course, outside of them you should have a `.container`.

Secondly you have a `.container` nested within your `<select>`, and then you do `col-12` inside of it. Why? You can safely remove `.row` and `.col-12` if you just want to create a row that takes up 100% width. *Bootstrap* `<div>` for example aready does that.

I assume you have a `.container` as the most-outter class. You shouldn't have another `.container` nested within another. You only need one container class per section.

After I clean up your code, your example runs fine:

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/jk7es2c8/22/

Again, we had no idea how your HTML structure looks like, and since you don't show your code, this kind of answer is what you will get. Or even your OP will be marked as off topic, unclear, etc.